# Отправка сообщения с вложением

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Добрый день.

Я отправляю сообщения через vk.api, используя метод messages.send:

```
vk.method('messages.send', {'user_id':user_id,'message':message, 'attachment':image})
```

Вопрос: как правильно записать параметр attachment, чтобы к сообщению прикреплялась фотография, взятая либо с сайта, либо с локального диска?

В [документации](https://vk.com/dev/messages.send) указывается, что attachment нужно записывать как: type.owner_id.media_id

В пример приводится запись photo100172_166443618

Пробовал записывать вместо attacment photo100172_166443618, но выдает ошибку. Уверен, что нужно как-то иначе записывать, но не знаю как, а в документации помощи не нашел.

Ошибка:

```
NameError: name 'photo100172_166443618' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> В случае, если прикрепляется объект, принадлежащий другому пользователю следует добавлять к вложению его access_key в формате , Например:
>   `video85635407_165186811_69dff3de4372ae9b6e`

Из той же страницы документации, на которую Вы давали ссылку. У меня тоже ошибка при открытии этого фото. Попробуйте добавить **access_key**, как в примере.

Должно получиться аля:

```
vk.method('messages.send', {'user_id':user_id,'message':message, 'attachment':photo100172_166443618_accessKey})
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!
Попробовал добавить access_key, но выдает ошибку также как и без нее. А если точно, то:

    NameError: name 'photo100172_166443618' is not defined

Comment: @123 потому что нужно в кавычках, это строка а не переменная

Comment: Большое спасибо вам обоим за ответы! Сейчас все работает. Вопрос закрыт.